# 500 error when returning a java object but not when a String is returned

Tags: java, jersey

I have been getting 500 error when the response is a java object. However, when i convert the object into a string, it is good.

```
  @GET
    @Path("/testJavaObj")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getJson() {
        SampleObj sampleObj = new SampleObj();

/* this converts the obj to String
String jsonObj = "";
        ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    try {
        jsonObj = ow.writeValueAsString(sampleObj);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
        return Response.ok(jsonObj).build();
/*

return Response.ok(sampleObj).build();
    }
```

public class SampleObj implements Serializable {

```
            private String sampleUrl = "sampleUrl";

            public String getSampleUrl() {
                return sampleUrl;
            }

            public void setSampleUrl(String sampleUrl) {
                this.sampleUrl = sampleUrl;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have next configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DemoApplication().configure(new SpringApplicationBuilder(DemoApplication.class)).run(args);
 }
}
```

Then I have Jersey config:

```
@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

public JerseyConfig() {
    register(Json.class);
 }
}
```

Then I have my json class:

```
@Path("/testJavaObj")
@Produces(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class Json {

@GET
public SampleObj getJson() {
    return new SampleObj();
 }
}
```

And finally SampleObj class:

```
public class SampleObj implements Serializable {
private String sampleUrl = "sampleUrl";

public String getSampleUrl() {
    return sampleUrl;
}

public void setSampleUrl(String sampleUrl) {
    this.sampleUrl = sampleUrl;
}
```

}

And everything is working for me.
The response is:

```
  {sampleUrl: "sampleUrl"}
```

Comment: thanks Dmitriy. Unfortunately, we are not using spring boot. this is a very old application before the advent of Spring boot. Based on my research, the only option is to use the ObjectMapper to convert the object into a String.